# Java derby over socket

Tags: java, sockets, javafx-2, derby

I have this new project in java. I connected the client to the server via TCP/IP over port 3000. It connects successfully... However, I also want to embed a database into the the server application and be able to query the database from the client end. 
What is the syntax for sending statements via a socket to the server application, which should query the database and send the data back to the client end?
e.g. "SELECT * FROM users"

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your own application networking protocol, you can use any syntax you want, though beware: this is a big project.

If you instead use the Derby Network Server and Derby Network Client to perform the client-server aspects of your application, you can use JDBC as the API for sending statements to the server and retrieving results back. See http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/getstart/twwdactivity4.html for a tutorial which demonstrates this.

Note that this is the most advanced of the Derby tutorials, so if you're unfamiliar with Derby and with Java, you should start with the first tutorial and work your way through them.